# Can linux use a mix of SHA-1 and CRYPT passwords?

Tags: users, password, encryption, shadow

We have an automated sync-routine that uses `useradd` to create new users on a Ubuntu 10.04 machine. The application launching the routine provided both username and `CRYPT`-encrypted password. However, since we changed how passwords are handled in order to include LDAP support, passwords now don't have to be `CRYPT` but can also be `MD5` or `SHA-1`. In fact, `SHA-1` is the new default. This however now causes problems.

I have read up on how `/etc/shadow` is handled and there doesn't seem to be an id for `SHA-1`, only for `SHA-256`/`SHA-512`(`$5$` and `$6$` respectively). The only thing I found was to change the whole thing from `CRYPT` to `SHA-1`. We could do that, but we wanted the whole transition to be as non-disruptive as possible.

**Is there a way to use both `CRYPT` and `SHA-1` passwords together?**

NOTES
 - The main application is a CMS on an entirely different server. The linux server in question is a local machine(slave) at the client's location in order to provide local services.
 - We are aware that we could switch the entire system out to use LDAP-only, but, as outlined earlier, we don't want to change everything at once.

Comment: I don't see why you *couldn't* use different password hashing mechanisms on the same system, as long as they are all supported by the system. According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/9133085/486504 `$5$` is SHA-1. Did you *actually try* this, and *what exact problems* did you encounter?

Comment: We tried using both $5$ and $6$, neither of which worked. All other services that received hashes from the CMS worked without trouble. 'useradd' actually didn't put the hash into /etc/shadow itself, it only put a '=' character in its place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not authenticate those users for which you only have an unsalted SHA-1 hash of their password by another means than `/etc/shadow`.

Using PAM, you can have as many authentication modules as you want and stack them as you want. You can keep `pam_unix.so` for some users and use `pam_ldap.so` for the rest.

Comment: Will take a look into PAM and come back with questions (or possibly/hopefully to accept this answer).